# Como comparar caracteres de um arquivo externo com a tabela ASCII em C?

Tags: c

Eu preciso fazer um programa em C que lê um arquivo externo com caracteres dentro e verifica se o código dos caracteres está entre os códigos >32 e <126 da tabela ASCII. 
Se estiver entre o código 32 e 126 eu retorno "Contém na tabela"+caractere
Se não estiver entre esse espaço de código eu retorno "Não contém na tabela"+caractere.
Eu fiz dessa forma, mas o "else" está retornando caracteres diferentes do que digito.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main(void)
{
  FILE *pont_arq;

  int c=0;
  char palavra[20];

  pont_arq = fopen("arquivo.txt", "rt");

do
{
    c = getc(pont_arq);

    if (c >= 32 && c <= 126){
        printf(" | %c %i contem na tabela", c, c);
    }else
    {
        printf("\n\n %i nao contem na tabela ", c, c);
    }

} while (c != EOF);

  fclose(pont_arq);

return(0);
}
```

Comment: Eu entendo o modo de abertura `r`, `r+` e `rb`, agora o que é o modo de abertura `rt` usado ali pelo `fopen`?

Comment: @JeffersonQuesado algumas implementações consideram caracteres diferentes dos padronizados. Neste caso, o "t" simbolizaria um arquivo de texto (que obviamente deve existir). No z/OS da IBM esse recurso está disponível.

Comment: Mostre um exemplo, de preferência pequeno, de um trecho da entrada, e também da saída, que contenha "caracteres diferentes do que digito". Note que no printf do else você informa apenas o formato pra uma variável mas na função informa duas variáveis.

Comment: A entrada coloquei "hjç" (sem aspas), nesse caso a saída foi:
"h 104 contém na tabela   |  j 106 contém na tabela  |  195 não contém na tabela  |  167 não contém na tabela  |  -1 não contém na tabela".
Mas a saída deveria ter sido apenas "h 104 contém na tabela   |  j 106 contém na tabela  |  ç 135 não contém na tabela".

Comment: A tabela ASCII padrão define apenas os caracteres de 0 a 127. Ela não contempla caracteres acentuados e especiais, no caso seu `ç`. Talvez você deva trabalhar com a codificação de caracteres UTF-8 (preferencialmente) ou ainda a Latin1 (ISO/IEC 8859-1) para tratar de caracteres não representados na tabela ASCII.

Answer (score 1):

O problema é que você lê o final de arquivo (EOF), testa se o caracter está dentro da tabela ou não, e só depois testa de deve terminar o loop (c != EOF). Não faria sentido testar mais nada, se você já chegou ao final do arquivo.

Quando você lê o EOF, que significa final de arquivo, não deve processar mais nada, deve sair imediatamente, pois você já chegou ao final de arquivo. Por acaso, o EOF vale -1, e é por isso que você está recebendo este output.

Basta colocar o teste em seu código da seguinte forma:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main(void)
{
  FILE *pont_arq;

  int c=0;
  char palavra[20];

  pont_arq = fopen("arquivo.txt", "rt");

  do
  {
    c = getc(pont_arq);

    if(c != EOF) {
      if (c >= 32 && c <= 126){
          printf(" | %c %i contem na tabela", c, c);
      } else {
          printf("\n\n %i nao contem na tabela ", c, c);
      }
    }
  } while (c != EOF);

  fclose(pont_arq);

  return(0);
}
```